# Use of Signed Encryption Scope while generating account/service SAS token and how to setup it in Azure portal?

Tags: azure-blob-storage

Want to use signed encryption scope while generating SAS token and then get a blob which has used same scope during the time of upload. Currently it's throwing 403- unauthorized error when I try to fetch a blob which was uploaded to backend using same customer-managed encryption key.

Answer (score 0):

This error may cause if the key has been disabled or deleted, access to customer-managed keys has been revoked, or your access token activation time is expired

Please check that you followed the below workaround correctly
[image]

After clicking key vault and key, try to generate a new key vault and key after clicking them to prevent an error. In ***Encryption scopes check you have given valid key vault and key and infrastructure encryption should be Enable as below***

[image]

when you try to fetch a blob which was uploaded to backend using same customer-managed encryption key check whether your authentication type should be in account key, and you choose existing scope is valid as below

[image]

Once you upload a blob ensure you have generate SAS token and URL and try to use blob SAS URL for accessible

***Reference:*** [Authorize with Shared Key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-requests-to-azure-storage) and [Forbidden (403), Unauthorized (401),](https://auth0.com/blog/forbidden-unauthorized-http-status-codes/)